# How to dynamically set the sorting parameter order with null last in django API?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am receiving sort_by and sort_order as query parameters into our Django API. I have the logic originally like this:

```
class Users:
    queryset = ...
    sort_by = self.request.query_params.get('sort_by')
    sort_order = self.request.query_params.get('sort_order')

    if sort_order == "desc":
        sort_by = "-" + sort_by
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        return queryset.order_by(sort_by, "id")
```

The issue I ran into is that when I sort by descending order by a specific parameter, the null values will show up first. I want all null values to be last no matter if I'm sorting asc or desc. I saw that there's a function from the Django docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/expressions/#using-f-to-sort-null-values-1) but that would mean that I have to have a different function call for whether it's ascending or descending which would make it not elegant:

```
if sort_order == 'desc':
    return queryset.order_by(F(sort_by).desc(nulls_last=True), "id")
else:
    return queryset.order_by(F(sort_by).asc(nulls_last=True), "id")
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if not sort_order:
   sort_order = "asc"
return queryset.order_by(getattr(F(sort_by),sort_order))(nulls_last=True), "id")
```

I think??

although im not sure thats more elegant than just using 2 calls...

im also not sure what order

`queryset.order_by(F("-pk").asc())` would give?
it might just be the same as `order_by(F("pk").desc())`?

I would probably just do something along the lines of

```
order_by_clause = F(sort_by).asc(nulls_last=True)
if sort_order == "desc":
   order_by_clause = F(sort_by).desc(nulls_last=True)
return queryset.order_by(order_by_clause,"id")
```

If it was me

Comment: Your last code snippet looks reasonable, I’m just trying to avoid rewriting the entire thing again with only asc() or desc() being the only explicit difference.